# How can I mend a broken bathroom sink drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing, repair, pipe

I removed the P-trap from underneath my bathroom sink and cleaned out a messy clog. (Blech!)

I thought all was going well, but as I was reinstalling the trap, the metal pipe detached from from the stub of piping leading down from the top of the sink (as in the photo). It felt like the two pieces had been very lightly sealed together.

In your answer, please take into account my basic plumbing knowledge. If you use a term fancier than "pipe," please define it.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Does it look like the lower piece threads on to the upper piece? What are their relative diameters?

Comment: They have identical diameters. One cannot be inserted into or screwed onto the other. It's as if they were stuck together to form one unit and then came apart in my hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to replace is the "drain assembly" or "pop up". Here's a link to a sample:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Delta-Push-Pop-Up-Drain-Assembly-in-Chrome-with-Overflow-Holes-72173/204154080

There's every chance you've got a 1-1/4", but maybe it's 1-1/2", so bring your old part with you to the plumbing place or big box.

Don't buy a plastic one. They're terrible.

I'm assuming you've not got a lever assembly to close the drain. (Typically, that's a little rod behind the faucet.) Just be sure to buy one that matches what you have now.

Beyond that, you'll need a big wrench to undo/redo the nut, and some plumber's putty to get back in business. (Some instructions these days suggest silicone around the top of the assembly... I wouldn't do it.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have a lever assembly. I do have some heavy duty wrenches, so I'll remove the part and head on over to home depot (or wherever). I'll keep you posted on progress.

Comment: Umm... when I grip that big nut at the bottom with a wrench and twist, the whole assembly rotates.

Comment: @AdamHrankowski You can probably use a medium-sized screwdriver going down into the drain (from top) into a hole (kinda angled down and to the side) to keep the whole thing from rotating.

Comment: Bingo. That did it. Had my teenage son hold it steady with a pair of pliers. I taught him everything I know about being handy. That took about 5 minutes.